# NullPointerException, even though object is pointing to the FXML instance

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

(I am using Scene Builder...)

Here is the `MusicGeneratorGUI` class...

```
public class MusicGeneratorGUI extends Application {
    @FXML private Sphere icon;
    ...
}
```

Here I have instantiated the object from the FXML file with the same ID...

```
<Sphere fx:id="icon" ... />
```

However, `System.out.println(icon);` in the main method of the controller class produces null.

The 'icon' Sphere object is null.

Here is the main class... ('controller class')

```
public class Main implements Initializable {
    @FXML public static Sphere icon;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        //Nothing here...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: do you have inside your .fxml file information about this controller class? 
I mean: fx:controller="MusicGeneratorGUI"

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly .. needs application, controller (you don't expect the controller to be the same instance as the app, do you? - if you do, that's plain wrong and requires to work through a tutorial on fxml to understand its mechanics ;), fxml and complete stacktrace

Comment: @Abra yeah and thanks, I'm aware that trying word jokes in a foreign language is .. a daring endeavour :)

Comment: I think it would help if you posted your FXML file. Or at least the line[s] containing the `xmlns` and `fx:controller` attributes.

Comment: no .. read that darn help page _and_ my comment carefully and follow it (what you show must be minimal, reproducible, complete). That added snippet makes no sense at all .. (take a step back and learn how to build a ui with fxml from a tutorial, follow it by letter, then adapt to your needs without changing the basic structure). And note, you __must not__ try to inject static fields.

Comment: `@FXML private Sphere icon;` inside of the Application class is incorrect. That code should be in the Controller only.

Comment: If you use `fx:controller` in your FXML file then the `FXMLLoader` will, by default, create a new instance of the specified class via reflection. That instance will be different than the instance of `MusicGeneratorGUI` that had `#start(Stage)` invoked. Consequently the FXML-injected field will be injected for one instance but not the other. Now, there are ways around this problem but the best solution is to follow best practices—make the controller a separate class from the application class.

Comment: Also, `static` fields cannot be injected.

Comment: The documentation isn't clear to me. You might need to call loader.load before calling getController.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating one or more Answers, is against Stack Exchange policy (even when your original question wasn't what you intended). Your most recent edit here did invalidate an answer. In such cases, you *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)* instead, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your loader.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
```

Then you can get access to an instance of your controller.

```
Main main = loader.getController();
```

Then you can access the `icon` from the controller.

```
System.out.println(main.icon);
```

Note, you can still get the parent via.

```
Parent root = loader.load();
```

You might want to consider doing this from the initialize method of the controller, then you don't need to expose the icon of the Controller. Also, why is your icon static? I think you need to ditch the static.

Comment: @RainbowDoritosAreMine I didn't write to use "load", I said to use "new FXMLLoader(...)".

Comment: @RainbowDoritosAreMine your question is still incomplete. The best case is to make a complete example. FXML, Controller, and the Application classes that can reproduce your problem. I'm not sure how you are check if the icon is null. Did you delete the line `@FXML private Sphere icon;` from you MusicGeneratorGui class?

Comment: Hey. :(( How can I make this a better question please?

Comment: @RainbowDoritosAreMine Your example isn't complete. There are relevant details that are missing, such as you've declared two different `Sphere icon` but you don't show how you're accessing it to show it is null. I don't know if it's worth your time to fix it, but if you do I can give you an upvote. :D

Comment: Sorry, *three* icons.